# PostgreSQL, Inner Join SELECT using three tables

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, inner-join

I have three tables in my database; walls, keys and wallAccessKeys.

```
CREATE TABLE walls (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(50)
);

INSERT INTO walls (name)
VALUES ('Test Wall');

CREATE TABLE keys (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    key VARCHAR(50)
);

INSERT INTO keys (key)
VALUES ('testingtesting123');

CREATE TABLE wallAccessKeys (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  keyID INT,
  wallID INT
);

INSERT INTO wallAccessKeys (keyID, wallID)
VALUES (1, 1);
```

Walls should only be accessible with certain keys, the keys that access each wall is stored in the `wallAccessKeys` table.

Walls have many keys, keys open many walls.

I'm trying to write an SQL statement to select `wall.ID` given `keys.key` value.

I've gotten so far using an Inner Join on `wall` and `wallAccessKeys` but can't figure this out.

```
SELECT *
FROM walls
INNER JOIN wallAccessKeys
ON walls.ID = wallAccessKeys.wallID
```

Is using Inner join the best way to do this? If so please, could someone help me with the SQL?

To summarize, I need an SQL statement where I can provide a key value e.g. testingtesting123, and get a list of walls that key has access to.

Comment: are you sure you need `wallAccessKeys.id` you could set a constraint to do that `CONSTRAINT charge_template_charge_unit_pk PRIMARY KEY (keyID, wallID)  -- explicit pk
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to figure this out using another inner join. Solution bellow if anyone needs it.

```
SELECT walls.id
        FROM walls
        INNER JOIN wallAccessKeys
        ON walls.id = wallAccessKeys.wallID
        INNER JOIN keys
        ON keys.id = wallAccessKeys.keyID and keys.key = 'testingtesting123'
```